# Inverting the function $f(x)=x\cdot C^x$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation, inverse-function

Let $C>0$ be a positive constant. Then consider the function

$$
f(x)=x\cdot C^x.\qquad(x>0)
$$

How do I compute $f^{-1}(y)$?

So far, I have only been able to derive
$$
\begin{align*}
y=x\cdot C^x\iff\log(y)&=\log(x\cdot C^x)
\\
&=\log(x)+\log(C^x)
\\
&=\log(x)+x\log(C).
\end{align*}
$$
However, I do not see how I would isolate and make $x$ the "subject".

Comment: Numerically or rewriting this as $\;\displaystyle z= w\, e^w\;$ using [LambertW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (many answers provided searching LamberW here!).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Mathematica gives me $f^{-1}(y)=\frac{W(\log(C)y)}{\log(C)}$, with some errors. Is that along the right lines?

Comment: Yes simply set $w:=\log(C)\,x\,$ so that $\;\log(C)\,y= w\, e^w\,$ and use the definition of $W$ (LambertW was created specifically for this kind of problems). Fine continuation,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni ah, so actually, $f^{-1}(y)=W(\log(C)y)$?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. Hi, Raymond ! Long time no speak. How are you doing in this terrible time ? Take care. Cheers :-)

Comment: @JasonBorn: well you have to multiply by $log(C)$ on both sides first so that the anwer provided by alpha should be right (you have to divide by $\log(C)$).

Comment: Hi dear @Claude I am fine thank you (working at home which is not so difficult for a software dev :-)). I hope you are well too not that you appeared otherwise from your very regular productivity here! :-) All the best and take care! Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Yes, you are right. I forgot about the substitution we made.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve the equation analytically by using elementary functions. You can compute numerical approximations if that's what you need.

Comment: Is an analytic solution possible with say Lambert's W function?

Comment: Yes. Substitute $y=x\log C$.